# JAVA Printing out output data in existing excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, printing

I'm working on script in **Java**, that will:

1. go to the website
2. pull data from an excel sheet (address)
3. input address
4. click search button and get output data in two separate fields on the website.
5. **print out the output data in two columns of existing excel file (if not possible, then at least NEW txt file separated with "|" )**
6. repeat process from points 2-5 for all the rows in mentioned excel sheet.

The problem is with point 5. I'm not sure how to edit existing excel file. Or what would be the command for creating new file and print out data row by row accordingly.

Comment: Hello !!! please post your sample code and let us know where it failed .It would be difficult to a reader to uderstand this way.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post the code that you have tried so far and and the problem/error you are facing.